# Django Template Language Shows Up In Webpage

Tags: django, django-templates

My Django template language tags are showing up when the webpage is run on the test server. Does anyone know why that may be happening? (Everything else on the webpage is displaying properly, and the tags are even doing their jobs. I just don't know why the text is there.

The page's html:

```
 <% extends "base.html" %> 


<% block page_title %> Challenges <% endblock %>

<% block content %> 
<ul> 
    {% for month in months%}
    <li> <a href="{% url 'month-challenge' month %}">{{month|title}} </a></li>

    
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <% endblock %> 



The template that the page is inheriting from: 

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{% block page_title %} {% endblock %}</title> 
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}
    
</body>
</html>
```

[What the output looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3b6d.png)

I've looked at similar posts on here and none of those fixes seemed to apply here (opening the html doc directly, Leaving a space between the { and %, etc.

Comment: Look at your html very carefully. You have at least 4 lines that contain `<%` and `%>` instead of `{%` and `%}`. Those are the lines that are showing up in your browser.

Comment: Oh wow thank you so much, you legitimately saved me the ~3 years that it would've taken me to notice that!!

Answer (score 1):

Template tags are wrapped in a `{% … %}`, not <s>`<% … %>`</s>

You thus implement this with:

```
{% extends "base.html" %} 

{% block page_title %} Challenges {% endblock %}

{% block content %} 
  <ul> 
    {% for month in months%}
    <li> <a href="{% url 'month-challenge' month %}">{{month|title}} </a></li>

    
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endblock %}
```